# Angularjs - Checkbox value update in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a simple working hours directive using angularjs. My modal array which looks like this

```
scope.model = [
    { name: 'Sunday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: '' },
    { name: 'Monday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: ''  },
    { name: 'Tuesday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: ''  },
    { name: 'Wednesday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: ''  },
    { name: 'Thursday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: ''  },
    { name: 'Friday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: ''  },
    { name: 'Saturday', selected: false, openhoursFrom: '', openhoursTo: ''  },
];
```

What I wanted to do is when a user clicks on a specific checkbox, it suppose to update the that particular day `selected: true`. I cant seem to achieve this instead when i click is either nothing happens or everything is selected. What should I do to fix this problem?

Here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/bM9kKQTSR9G9a31hvr71) to the plunkr demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses camelcase for directive definitions but dashes in html markup. See the doc on [normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

> We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase
>   normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is
>   case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case
>   forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g.
>   ng-model).

You should be using

```
ng-model="day.selected"
```

and not

```
ngModel="day.selected"
```

See [working forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWF9LzeKNbD300JtkKcl?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Please add the checkbox change event to update the model selected state

```
elem.bind('change', function (evt) {
        angular.forEach(scope.model, function (v) {
            if (v.name == evt.target.value) {
              v.selected = evt.target.checked;
              scope.$apply();
            }
        });
      });
```

you can see the full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dpch5MvJQDIOK1VdcioH?p=preview)

Comment: This is the worst approach one could imagine for Angular app. There are directive that help with binding, which is the strong part of Angular. But making model updates manually eliminates the reasons to use Angular as framework...